# FreeSWITCH: Unable to connect from browser(WebRTC) behind enterprise firewall

Tags: webrtc, voip, nat, freeswitch, turn

I am running a FreeSWITCH server on a public domain. I am able to make call from my browser(WebRTC with sipjs) to the FreeSWITCH server from a direct Internet connection.

I am testing it on a Firewall that allows only TCP on port 443. I am running a separate TURN server. I am trying to connect from my browser by specifying TURN server with credentials. I am unable to make it work. PeerConnection is getting closed.

1. FreeSWTICH server is NOT behind Firewall
2. Client(browser) is behind Firewall
3. TURN server is available

Is there any configuration I have to do either in FreeSWITCH server or in the  client end(javascript) to make it work?

Comment: My TURN server is listening on port 443. Following is the error I am getting in the FreeSWITCH Server. 
`[INFO] mod_dialplan_xml.c:637 Processing anonymous <anonymous>->7500 in context default
[WARNING] switch_core_media.c:3465 NO candidate ACL defined, Defaulting to wan.auto [NOTICE] switch_channel.c:3809 Hangup sofia/internal/anonymous@<my_domain_name> [CS_EXECUTE] [INCOMPATIBLE_DESTINATION] switch_core_session.c:1665 Session 1 (sofia/internal/anonymous@<my_domain_name>) Ended switch_core_session.c:1669 Close Channel sofia/internal/anonymous@<my_domain_name> [CS_DESTROY]`

Answer (score 1):

You need to open UDP ports, cause signalling will go via WSS and media via UDP ports:

`mod_sofia to serve SIP signaling via WSS and media via SRTP/DTLS.`

https://www.packtpub.com/books/content/configuring-freeswitch-webrtc

Comment: UDP ports are blocked in the firewall. Only outgoing TCP connections on port 443 are allowed. I hope TURN server will do the job. I assume TURN will accept media data via TCP connections on port 443 and relay it as UDP to the FreeSWITCH server.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use a TURN server. You will have to configure it to listen on port 443 with TCP, because by default a TURN server listens on port 3478.

However, if the Firewall checks for a TLS connection (i.e. for HTTPS), you will have to configure the TURN server as a TURNS (TURN over TLS).

Comment: My TURN server is listening on port 443.

Following is the error I am getting in the FreeSWITCH Server.
`[WARNING] switch_core_media.c:3465 NO candidate ACL defined, Defaulting to wan.auto
[NOTICE] switch_channel.c:3809 Hangup sofia/internal/anonymous@<my_domain_name> [CS_EXECUTE] [INCOMPATIBLE_DESTINATION]
switch_core_session.c:1665 Session 1 (sofia/internal/anonymous@<my_domain_name>) Ended
switch_core_session.c:1669 Close Channel sofia/internal/anonymous@<my_domain_name> [CS_DESTROY]`